# Product filter on product listing page

Tags: magento-1.8, filter, collection-filtering

I want to filter products on product listing page and show only configurable products type.

In catalog/product/list.phtml file after

`$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();` I'm adding

```
 // First make a copy, otherwise the rest of the page might be affected!
$_productCollection = clone $this->getLoadedProductCollection();

// Unset the current products and filter before loading the next.

$_productCollection->clear()
                   ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
                   ->load();
```

On product listing page I'm getting an error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in 'where clause'`.

> Note: I'm using Amasty product filter extension.

Comment: amitshree, have you got any solution?

Comment: @MagentoLearner: yes. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65694/hide-configurable-product-with-child-product-availability-out-of-stock-from-prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO NO NO.

if you want to do this on *ALL* pages, just deactivate or remove all the simples from the website.

If you want to do it only for certain pages, you should implement an observer which hooks into `catalog_block_product_list_collection` and add your filters there.

Reloading the product list costs performance for no win.

Comment: Fabian, my target is to hide all the configurable products for which even a single simple product is out of stock.