# Hide configurable product with child product availability out of stock from product listing page

Tags: event-observer, filter, collection-filtering

I want to hide all the configurable products from product listing page for which even a single associated simple product is out of stock. For it first of all I'm trying to filter all configurable products but I'm getting the below  error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.type_id' in
>   'where clause'

I'm using `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event.

Here is events section code from config.xml.

```
<events>
            <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <observers>
                    <retailon_configurable_list>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>retailon_configurable/observer</class>
                        <method>addInStockOnlyFilter</method>
                    -</retailon_configurable_list>              
                </observers>
            </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        </events>
```

Here is `observer` code:

```
<?php

class Retailon_Configurable_Model_Observer {
    /**
   * Observes the catalog_block_product_list_collection event
   */
  public function addInStockOnlyFilter($observer){
  $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');

    }
}
```

How can I filter products in my `observer` provided the given conditions?

Comment: Sure you can try to add such filters, but my question is: why don't you just assign only configurable products on this category?

Comment: There will be simple as well as configurable products on this category.  How assigning only configurable products to this category will help? Requirement is that all the configurable products from category page should be hidden for which even a single associated simple product is out of stock.

Comment: If I clearly understand you. You have conf product with 2 associated products. And when they are both 'out of stock' you want to hide such conf product from product listing ?

Comment: No. I have a conf product with 2 associated products and one of them is "in stock" and one is "out of stock" and I want to hide the conf product.

Comment: try to modify method isVisible(). Put smth like "if one of the children not in stock then return false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working. Here is the observer code:

```
<?php

class Retailon_Configurable_Model_Observer {

  public function addInStockOnlyFilter($observer){
    $productCollection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        if ($product->getTypeId() == "configurable"){
            $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $product);
            foreach ($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getUsedProducts ( null, $product) as $simple) {
            //all associated product
                if($simple->getStockItem()->getQty() < 1 ){
                    $proArray[] = $product->getId();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    if(count($proArray)){
        foreach ($proArray as $key) {
            $productCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
        }
    }

    $observer->getEvent()->setCollection($productCollection);
        }

}
```

Comment: Filtering the loaded collection with PHP will result in less products being shown. For example if you have a page size of 10 and 5 products are removed, you only see 5 products. Also the total number of products and pages will be shown wrong. A solution with real collection filters would be better (though more complicated)